# Alternative to rules for User-Defined Data Types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Since the rules are deprecated, what is the correct syntax to use constraints with User-defined types (I don't mean user-defined table types)?

```
CREATE TYPE MyType
FROM NCHAR(10) NOT NULL    
CONSTRAINT CHECK(MyType IN ('haha', 'hoho'))
```

This is not working...

Comment: I don't think SQL Server supports constraints on user-defined scalar types.

Comment: @Gordon: Can I still use rules than?

Comment: Pretty sure rules were deprecated in 2005. They might still work today but I wouldn't use them.

Comment: @Sean: Does that mean that there is no way to enforce a constraint for user-defined scalar types ? In this case user-defined scalar types would become pretty useless.

Comment: @Schwammkopf yes - pretty useless. See Erland's wishlist for this exact problem [here](http://www.sommarskog.se/wishlist.html#Domains). And vote if you agree.

Comment: @Smor: Please write it as an answer so i can accept it.